# Reflection from the plane mirror

Tags: geometric-optics

A surveyor on one bank of canal observed the image of the 4 inch and 17 ft marks on a vertical staff, which is partially immersed in the water and held against the bank directly opposite to him, coincides. If the 17ft mark and the surveyor's eye are both 6ft above the water level, estimate the width of the canal. Refractive index of water is 4/3
**Attempt**: I'm not able to understand the language of the question

Comment: Suggestion: try drawing a picture and then maybe people can tell you if your interpretation is wrong.

Comment: That's the problem... I can't get to understand what's actually happening

Comment: Surely you can draw a picture involving a man, a canal, and a vertical staff. If you don't know what the words mean you need a dictionary.

Comment: I agree. It is not obvious. I did not understand it until I read Farcher's answer. But your problem is the confusing description given in the question, rather than any difficulty understanding physics. So I think the question is not useful to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Light from the 17 ft mark, which is in the air, is reflected off the surface of the water in the canal and enters the eye of the surveyor.
Light from the 4 inch mark, which is below the surface of the water, is refracted at the surface of the water in the canal and enters the eye of the surveyor.

Comment: U mean that both rays should travel same path after reflection and refraction

Comment: Yes. That is what he means.